# adt bundle version compatible to API 19

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I need to download android 19 API compatible eclipse adt bundle and I know I can find the versions with this link:

**http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-YYYYMMDD.zip**

But the problem comes up as I can not find the release date of that version, So I can not download. whoud you please help me.

Comment: Please post the link to download adt-bundle-linux-x86-YYYYMMDD.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with deeper search.I finally find it.the release date was 2013/10/30 So you can download it from

http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030.zip